# How to rewrite this gitlab yml file to docker file

Tags: docker, gitlab, dockerfile, gitlab-ci-runner

I need your help in executing the below gitlab yaml file in docker file ,basically i want to make the contents of this gitlab yaml file as a docker container and execute in kubernetes..here is gitlab yaml file

```
 stages:
   - auto-test-pre-stage
   - auto-test-stage
   - test

  variables:
   BUCKET_NAME: junitreports/CompanionAppSimulator
   AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: us-east-2

  test:
   image: python:latest
   stage: test
   tags:
     - docker
   before_script:
     - pip install awscli
   script:
     - echo 'this is the script 2'
     - cd /builds/core-systems/find/test/Companion/report/
     - ls -l
     - aws s3 cp . s3://${BUCKET_NAME}/${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}/-$(date +"%m-%d-%y-%T") --recursive
   environment:
   name: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
   url: http://${BUCKET_NAME}.s3-website.${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
  only:
    - branches
  except:
    - master


   .auto_test_template: &auto_test_definition  # template for deploy jobs
    image: katalonstudio/katalon
    stage: auto-test-pre-stage
   tags:
     - docker
   script:
     - cd test/CompanionAppSimulator
     - katalon-execute.sh -retry=0 -statusDelay=15 -testSuitePath="Test Suites/AppSimulator"   
     artifacts:
      name: "Test Reports"
      paths:
        - /builds/core-systems/finders-keepers/test/CompanionAppSimulator/report/
     reports:
         junit:
        - '/builds/core-systems/finders-keepers/test/CompanionAppSimulator/report/*.xml'

     auto_test_feature:
     <<: *auto_test_definition
  tags:
    - docker
  only:
    - branches
      except:
       - master
       - develop

    auto_test_develop:
          <<: *auto_test_definition
      tags:
        - docker
      only:
        - develop

    auto_test_stage:
      <<: *auto_test_definition
      stage: auto-test-stage
       tags:
        - docker
      only:
        - master
      when: manual
```

Any other alternatives to make the above contents of file to execute as docker container ..is there any other way to achieve this scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not run the gitlab-ci file on kubernetes cluster, this file is specific to gitlab if you want to use this file for CI purpose.

P.S. What do want to achieve by running yaml file on Kubernetes cluster?
Edit: I understand that you want your own image to handle CI part without using Gitlab.

Comment: You can write your own code to implement CI using any language and then you can dockerize that.